# Rails email scheduling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionmailer

Im working on an app where users enter certain dates they want to reminded of (birthdays, anniversaries, holidays ect).. I need to setup an automated email that goes out 2 weeks, 1 week, and 1 day prior to the date(s) they select.

Whats the best way to go about this in a rails 3 app?

I have mandrill(smtp) and Mailchimp accounts..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Setup a rake task that checks if any emails need to be sent and then send them within the task. Then, use the heroku addon garbage collection mentioned to run 'rake my_email_task' where my_email_task is the name of your custom task.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this on Heroku by any chance?

[Heroku has an add-on for this kind of task.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler)

Comment: yes i am! does it let you send user specific content in the email?.. Im sending deals to users based on their city..

Comment: it seems to only "The scheduler add-on will run any number of commands against your app, either every 10 minutes, every hour, or every day.".. I need it based on the dates the user enters, not something i enter.

Comment: @NKeating just setup a scheduler to run a rake task every x minutes (say 10). The rake task should check for any emails with dates in the past that haven't been sent. This will give ensure that the emails get sent within 10 minutes of the deadline. If you need more accuracy you can use a worker (heroku recommends using clock) but given you are sending at most 1 day before the even this should be fine.

Comment: @SteveSmith thanks!.. so say someone sets a reminder for August 1.. and i need the 3 reminders sent 2 weeks, 1 week, and 1 day before.. does that logic go in a mailer or controller?

Comment: I would personally put it in the model I think. Something along the lines of find_due_reminders. Then just pass that array of reminders to the mailer?